# how to do 2 php while loops with 1 mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to run only one query using php & mysql and then do two while loops with different results. i

```
//this is the query
$qry_offers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM offers ORDER BY offer_end ASC");
```

in the first loop, i want to show any result which has an "end_date" less or equal than today

```
<div id="current">
<?
while($row_offers = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_offers)) {
    if ( (date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) <= ($row_offers['offer_end']) ) {
        echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row_offers['offer_name'].'</a></li>';
    }
}
?>
</div><!-- END OF CURRENT -->
```

in the second loop, i want to show any result which has an "end_date" greater than today

```
//this is where i would have the 2n while loop
<div id="inactive">
<?
   while($row_offers = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_offers)) {
    if ( (date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) > ($row_offers['offer_end']) ) {
        echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row_offers['offer_name'].'</a></li>';
    }
}
?>
</div><!-- END OF INACTIVE -->
```

Comment: have you tried it?   what is not working about this?

Comment: @bretterer: yes, i tried it and i only get results for the 1st loop. the second is blank

Comment: use `mysql_field_seek($qry_offers,0)`  before second loop but I prefer Ansrew's answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to save the results from each loop and then put them together at the end.

```
$offers_current = array();
$offers_inactive = array();

while($row_offers = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_offers)) {
    if ( (date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) <= ($row_offers['offer_end']) )
        $offers_current[] = '<li><a href="#">'.$row_offers['offer_name'].'</a></li>';
    if ( (date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) > ($row_offers['offer_end']) )
        $offers_inactive[] = '<li><a href="#">'.$row_offers['offer_name'].'</a></li>';
}

?>
<div id="current">
    <ul>
    <?php echo implode("\n", $offers_current) ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="inactive">
    <ul>
    <?php echo implode("\n", $offers_inactive) ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for a single pass through the dataset. Could also replace the second if with an else now that they are right next to each other.

Comment: @Tony Not using `else` provides a slightly more generic solution, though the truth is I didn't see it. One of the most common mistakes I see in PHP is passing around huge data structures willy-nilly, like a resultset. It is just so much more scalable to process a resultset as you read it and I want to encourage that.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
$itemsArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_offers);
foreach ( $itemsArray as $row_offers ) {
    // ... Code in here for less than 'offer_end'
}
foreach ( $itemsArray as $row_offers ) {
    // ... Code in here for greater than 'offer_end'
}
```